# convergence of a special series concerning a function

Tags: calculus, analysis

Consider $S(f) = \{x:x>0, f(x)=x\},  \sum_{x\in S(f)} \frac{1}{x}$ converges for which of the following function?

A.) $\tan x$
B.) $\tan x^2$
C.) $\tan 2x$
D.) $\tan\sqrt{x}$
E.) $\sqrt{|\tan x|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. As regards A. note that the equation $\tan(x)=x$ has a unique solution $x_k$ in each interval $[k\pi,k\pi+ \frac{\pi}{2})$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}^+$ (why?). Therefore 
$$\sum_{x\in S(f)} \frac{1}{x}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x_k}> \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k\pi+ \frac{\pi}{2}}=+\infty.$$
On the other hand, as regards D, the equation $\tan(\sqrt{x})=x$ has a unique solution $x_k$ in each interval $[(k\pi)^2,(k\pi+ \frac{\pi}{2})^2)$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}^+$ (why?). Therefore
$$\sum_{x\in S(f)} \frac{1}{x}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x_k}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k\pi)^2}<+\infty.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: C.E should  be divergent for basically the same reason. But how about D?

Comment: @zach I edited my answer. Are you able to conclude now?